# ¿Qué alternativas puedo tener a utilizar una base de datos para este caso?

Tags: base-de-datos, diseño

He creado un módulo que actúa del siguiente modo:

1. Selecciono un texto dentro de un documento. digamos un trozo de una frase.
2. El módulo busca, dentro de la selección, ciertas palabras y las sustituye por otras.

Así de simple. Lo utilizo para sustituir expresiones recurrentes (sobretodo unidades de medida y abreviaturas) en documentos con los que estoy trabajando. Ejemplo.

```
Input = "En la Fig.3 se muestra una placa de 6 gsm."
```

seudo código:

```
10. buscar "Fig." y sustituirlo por "figura"

...

100. buscar "gsm" y sustituirlo por "g/m2"

...
```

etc

```
Output = "En la figura 3 se muestra una placa de g/m2."
```

El módulo tiene unas 100 líneas análogas a las dos anteriores. Asumo que la estrategia es completamente ineficiente pero aún así la ejecución es prácticamente instantánea de manera que no me plantearía afinarlo... si no fuera por lo incómodo que resulta añadir nuevos pares a la lista (tengo que ir al editor de VBA y meterlos a mano), además de que no me permite ver todos los pares a la vez en un listado. Como tampoco si sustituyo las cien líneas mencionadas por uno o dos Arrays.

Por ello estaba pensando crear una base de datos. Consistiría en tan sólo una tabla de cuatro columnas: palabra_origen, palabra_destino, MatchCase, WholeWord.

Pero quizás sea todavía más infeficiente crear una base de datos para algo tan simple como una sola tabla de cuatro campos y teniendo en cuenta que el módulo no va a realizar consultas combinando tablas, campos, etc, sino que únicamente va a leer una a una las entradas de la tabla.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: estas programando en VB6 ?

Comment: No Leandro, sólo en VBA. 

Llevo tiempo pensando en pasarme a VB lo que pasa que para lo que suelo necesitar en Word, voy tirando con VBA y al final no hago el esfuerzo de cambiar. Aparte que desconozco si la implementación de módulos tal como la tengo en plantillas DOT en VBA sería exportable a VB, me refiero a la funcionalidad, pero bueno eso sería tema de otra hebra.

De todos modos me interesa lo que puedas proponer sobre VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear la lista usando un archivo externo XML o JSON, seria mas cómodo modificar sin tener que instalar/usar un servicio de BD.
Existen librerías para usar XML/JSON sin problemas.

Comment: Arnau, lo que pasa es que sólo me manejo con VB. 

¿No valdría usar un archivo externo DOC para el mismo propósito en lugar de XML o JSON?

Comment: Un DOC lo dudo, pero un EXCEL seguramente si, seguro que hay alguna libreria para eso.

Comment: No si si entiendo exactamente lo que propones. Si se trata de utilizar un archivo externo no a través de un servicio de BD, ¿por qué no utilizar directamente un DOC con una tabla? ¿O incluso un txt?
Quiero decir que con un DOC no necesito ni siquiera buscar e instalar una librería...

Comment: Los DOC son documentos de texto con formato, no están diseñado para tratar con datos, daría demasiado trabajo filtrar toda la información inútil. XLS en cambio si está pensado para ello y seguramente puedas usarlo directamente.
Si no se pudierse, la idea es usar un fichero que solo trate datos sin formato, como son XML y JSON, la gracia es que VB seguro que ya dispone de librerias para tratarlos, otra manera seria usar un formato CVS, que es fácil de gestionar, y se puede usar directamente desde una hoja de cálculos como excel (creo que en XML también).

Answer (score 0):

Tanto Excel cómo `XML` o `JSON` son fáciles de actualizar y en el caso de Excel solo tienes que generar la tabla con los datos que necesitas buscar/sustituir y al ser ambos de `Microsoft` es muy fácil crear una macro para tu propósito.

Prueba algo cómo:

```
Sub Probando_Excel()

Dim oExl As Object, sName as String, sPath as String, sFName as String

'' Objeto para Excel
Set oExl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
'' Para que no sea visible
oExl.Visible = false

'' Ruta del archivo
sPath = "C:\Users\rafael.barragan\Documents\"
'' Nombre del archivo
sName = "ArchivoExcel.xlsx"
'' Nombre completo
sFName = sPath + sName
'' Abres archivo
oExl.workbooks.Open sFName

End Sub
```

puedes ver algo parecido [aquí](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/177760), y para eficientar las cosas mantenlo en memoria.

Comment: Bueno, ha pasado mucho tiempo pero estaba volviendo sobre esto. He aplicado lo indicado arriba por RafaBG y me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Bueno, ha pasado mucho tiempo, pero estaba volviendo sobre esto. He aplicado lo indicado arriba por RafaBG y veo que se abre correctamente la hoja de excel. Mi pregunta ahora es: ¿cómo doy las órdenes en VBA para desplazarme por la tabla de excel y recuperar los valores de las celdas?

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que necesites, puedes optar por copiar toda la tabla, algo cómo `Workbooks(sFName).Worksheets([Nombre_Hoja]).Range("A1:C10").Copy` o puedes filtrar con `AdvancedFilter`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta RafaBG. Lo que necesito es ir desplazándome por las celdas de un par de columnas de la hoja para recuperar sus valores con el fin de pasárselos a una variable en un bucle del propio código.

Comment: Para eso puedes intentar algo como `[...].Worksheets(...).Cells(i,j).Value` en este caso `i` y `j` son por coordenadas en filas y columnas respectivamente (ej. celda C4 = (4,3)) así puedes navegar por coordenadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias RafaBG. ¿Sabes si, una vez creado el objeto excel en el editor de VBA de Word, hay alguna forma de utilizar la ayuda de VBA de Excel en el editor de VBA de Word?

Comment: Disculpa RafaBG, ignora esta pregunta. Es solo que no tenía activada la Microsoft Excel 2.0 Object Library en la lista de referencias de Word VBA. Una vez activada ya veo la Ayuda para Excel dentro del editor de VBA Word. Pero gracias igualmente